# SQL is reversing the sort order on some queries, when no ORDER BY clause is provided

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table whose natural order is by its primary key `id`, so when I do

```
SELECT * from table
```

My result is ordered by `id`, **ascending**. However, every now and then, I will run a query on the table, without an `ORDER BY` clause, and the results are returned in order of `id` **descending**. Why is this happening? What would cause this, or what piece of information about how SQL works am I missing? What would determine the sort order of results when no `ORDER BY` clause is used? There are no `JOIN`s or `GROUP BY`s happening either.

The table is maintained in such a way that the desired order of any result is in `id` order **ascending** so that time consuming `ORDER BY`s never have to be run.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: SQL does not guarantee the ordering of query results unless `order by` is specified.  Two result sets are equivalent, even when they are in the same order.  If you want results in a particular order, then use `order by`.  If you order by a primary key or indexed columns, then the index is used for retrieval and no additional sort is necessary.

Comment: This questions has been answered here => http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6051

Comment: I did not know you were not guaranteed to get PK order without the `order by`. That was my "missing information about how SQL works." Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without an **order by** the ordering of your result is not defined. It is returned in a for your database system optimal way, in a way unpredictable. So it is pure coincidence that your **ids** will be delivered descending. The ordering could be changed by rebuilding the index or inserting/removing data into your table.